# Restructuring Infinite loop with Arrow Code

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement

I have an infinite loop with certain period (delay). I have the following structure:

```
// define the i32threshold of time
// set i32counter to 0
while(true)
{
  if(bExecuteEnable)
  {
    if(bConnectionSet)
    {
      if(++i32counter >= i32threshold)
      {
        // Do the job
        counter = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  delay(1); // 1 ms of delay introduces the period
}
```

Do you have any recommendation to restructure this infinite loop other than having all conditions merged into single `if`statement?

Comment: What's wrong with the loop as it is?

Comment: `delay (i32threshold);` might get rid of one condition, as written.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, it works but 4 nests looked too arrowish. I thought it could be changed.

Comment: Yes it can, you can use a single if statement as you've already said, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @AlanBirtles it is okay but I wanted to learn if there is any other practice that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten it looks a lot simpler:

```
while (!bExecuteEnable && !bConnectionSet && ++i32counter < i32threshold) {
  delay(1); // 1 ms of delay introduces the period
}

counter = 0;
```

Of course hopefully `i32threshold` is less than the maximum value of your `i32counter` or you're going to overflow and loop forever.